# Compilations errors displayed when running Eclipse on a JDK

Tags: java, eclipse

I just found a strange behavior with Lombok, Spring-Tool-Suite and the fact that I am running STS using the JDK in place of the JRE…

Here my current configuration in `STS.ini`:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.700.v20180518-1200
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\development\applications\Java\jdk-8\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx1200m
-javaagent:C:\development\applications\sts-3.9.5.RELEASE\lombok.jar
```

In the IDE, I get an error `The method […] is undefined for the type […]`.

[image: The method … is undefined for the type …]

Yet, the IDE seems to know that the method does really exist…

[image: The method does exist]

And as we can see, Lombok is correctly installed in STS.

[image]

But, if I use the following configuration with the JRE, no more lombok error, but a problem in my POM asking me to launch the IDE using the JDK:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.700.v20180518-1200
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\development\applications\Java\jre-8\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx1200m
-javaagent:C:\development\applications\sts-3.9.5.RELEASE\lombok.jar
```

[image: POM error, launch the IDE using a JDK]

Does anyone have any idea on how to manage Lombok in STS when running it using the JDK? As I don't really want to see any error…

---

***edit 01***

- STS version 3.9.5.RELEASE
- JDK and JRE version 1.8.0_172 64-Bit

I am setting the VM to use directly inside the `STS.ini` file for testing purpose. But, I do get the same errors when using the JDK or JRE from the `PATH` environment variable.

---

***edit 02***

Here the code of the `Insurance` bean:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
public class Insurance implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Size(max = 255)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 255)
    private String number;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "2018-01-01")
    private LocalDate validityPeriodBegin;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "2018-12-31")
    private LocalDate validityPeriodEnd;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;
}
```

---

***edit 03***

Just find out, but the errors I get in the IDE aren't limited to getter/setter generated by Lombok. I also get this kind of error from inheritance…

[image]

As we can see, both `save` and `deleteById` method are marked, yet theses methods are inherited from `CrudRepository`…

```
@Repository
public interface StructureRepository extends CrudRepository<Structure, String> {

    Collection<Structure> findByParentIsNull();

    Collection<Structure> findByParentId(String id);

    Collection<Structure> findByAgentsLogin(String login);
}
```

I have also tried to use the latest version of Eclipse in place of STS, and I get the exact same behavior.

And to finish, I tried launching the IDE using the JDK-10, and I didn't get another result…

**This mean that it is not related to Lombok, nor to STS…**
Maybe it is a problem related to **Eclipse** when launching it using a **JDK**?

Comment: I'm using Sts 3.9.4 but i didn't use any java path but its working .

Comment: Does `JRE` and `JDK` both set  in system properties?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking me if I have set the `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` environment variables? Then yes. But it isn't relevant to the question as I set the path to the JDK or the JRE directly inside the `STS.ini` file.

Comment: Your last two screenshots are irrelevant, as that is how the IDE should behave when using `javaw` from the `JRE`. I think that error is more of related to your code. Can you elaborate more on the setup of the entities as well as the annotations on them? I have a feeling it's related to some inheritance issue where you didn't specify child constructor args

Comment: Just in case, I have added the bean code in my post. But that's really a simple basic bean without much to it… No inheritance or whatever…

Answer (score 0):

I am now using **STS-4.0.0.RELEASE** in place of **STS-3.9.5.RELEASE**, and I am using the **JDK-11** in place of the **JDK-8**. The result: no more errors…

It was probably a bug which was fixed ever in **STS-4.0.0.RELEASE** or in the **JDK-11** as I didn't change much in the project configuration.